# How to implement Middleware service for Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, middleware, microsoft-dynamics

I want to connect to some external service from dynamics CRM that is protected with a certificate. Now I need to use middleware services to connect and perform the required operations. I have an wsdl file shared for the client, a SoapUI request and get a response from a Mock service.

I've tried to access the service using C# in Console application and the service returns me a response.

Now I just want to use the service in some middleware service and connect to it using microsoft dynamics code activities or Plugins.

Suggestions and recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you need to implement and what the transaction flow is.

As an example, in one instance we needed to display some information alongside CRM data, so we created a Web Resource with some Javscript code which invoked a plugin, which in itself called the web service and returned a JSON. Then used **KnockOut.js** to render it into the Web Resource.

In other instance we are developing a plugin which waits for some state on a Lead, validates information and if all is Ok invokes a Web Service to create the account in some other application. If that application is successful, then the plugin Qualifies the Lead and the flow continues in CRM.

If you need the Web Service invocation as part of the data for a transaction, you would probably want to have a plugin with an action to use in a workflow, or listen for some message on an entity to retrieve/validate/invoke your Web Service.

If you just need to display some information, you can create a Web Resource and it'll be simpler.

Some resources I found useful are:
 - [Tutorial: Write and register a plug-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/tutorial-write-plug-in)
 - [Creating Custom Actions for Dynamics 365 with C#](https://www.ashishvishwakarma.com/Writing-Custom-Actions-C-Sharp-Code-Dynamics-365/)
 - [How to Trigger Plugins on Custom Messages using Actions in Dynamics 365](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/dominicjarvis/2017/09/18/how-to-trigger-plugins-on-custom-messages-using-actions-in-dynamics-365)